# Java 14 records json serialization

Tags: java, json, jackson, gson, spring-webflux

Currently experimenting with the Records implements from java 14, everything looks nice but since the accessors are slightly different and jackson is not being able to deserialize and giving the following error:

```
Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: No serializer found for class com.x.x.x.xTracking and no properties discovered to create BeanSerializer (to avoid exception, disable SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS)
```

I checked all around the internet, including jackson and gson github to check the jep 359 support but havent found a single comment. Am i missing something really straight forward?

Yes i am aware that the java 14 is still not released and that records is only in preview in this version but would expect some comments at least.

Comment: Edit: By adding @JsonProperty at the java record definition it does serialize the annotated property. However how would be possible to configure the deserialization strategy of the public methods and not only traditional "getters" as the properties on the records does not start with get...

Comment: Records are a preview feature. Since nothing about them is final, including the API, no library is going to start supporting them because it will probably no longer work with the next iteration of records.

Comment: As records were introduced more then two years ago. They should be supported by now, right?

Answer (score 6):

Records support was added to Jackson 2.12.0 (https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-future-ideas/issues/46). It will be released in the next days.

Answer (score 2):

With "pure" Json-B you can do it this way:

```
public class RecordPropertyVisibilityStrategy implements PropertyVisibilityStrategy {
   @Override
   public boolean isVisible(Field field) {return true;}

   @Override
   public boolean isVisible(Method method) {return false;}
}
```

Then

```
@JsonbVisibility(RecordPropertyVisibilityStrategy.class)
public record MyRecord(Long id, String attr) {}
```

Answer (score 1):

For someone else experimenting, i went around, not proudly, with the following:

```
    @Bean
    public Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilderCustomizer jacksonCustomizer(){
        return builder ->
                builder.visibility(PropertyAccessor.FIELD, JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.ANY);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I did Jackson dealing with this problem in Spring Boot 2.4.1 application annotating the record with

```
@JsonAutoDetect(fieldVisibility = JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.ANY)
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, for Spring Boot 2.4.5 and Java 16, it may be enabled via `application.properties`, like so:

`spring.jackson.visibility.field=any`

See more on the [Spring Boot documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/appendix-application-properties.html#spring.jackson.visibility).